# How to perform an action only when capture is done in iphone image-Picker when ever click the capture button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

In my **iPhone** app i have **capture image** feature and to edit the captured image.

my intension is add a overlay to the image picker to change the dimensions of the crop rectangle visually [i will bother about it later]

When ever image picker opens the view is like this as follows:

[image]

**I need to know when the user clicks on that capture button**

I need to perform some actions **when ever user clicks on capture button** (`but not when the image picker appears / dismiss` ) `just before use the image by click` on **`use`**

at least ***print log statement*** **`NSLog(@" Capture Clicked");`**

Comment: have you find the solution dude

Comment: Did you get solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

assuming you are using UIImagePickerController. the method below will invoke after the user selected/captured image

```
   - (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
    {
        selectedImage =  [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
        [self editImage:selectedImage];
        //dismiss the picker
        [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    }
```

and of course that will make your app NOT responsive in cases like if your image processing method takes long time before it return.

Comment: the picker view dismiss when this method calls.....
i need to do action before dismiss (before **USE** the captured image)... any ways thaks for quick responce @ Mahesh & @ janusfidel